# How to configure axis length in manim? graph = Axes() not working

Tags: python, manim

I am using `manimce` and I wanted to change the axis length.
I tried

```
graph = Axes(
        x_length=6,
        y_length=3,
      )
```

This works fine on ordinary scenes but not working with `LinearTransformationScene`.

adding the `graph = Axes()` portion **does nothing**...

The above code in an ordinary scene:
[image]

The same code in a Linear Transformation scene:

[image]

Why is this so? Doesn't `graph = Axes()` work with `LinearTransformationScene`?

---

Full code:

```
from manim import *

class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):

def __init__(self):
    LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
        self,
        show_coordinates=True,
        leave_ghost_vectors=True,
      )
 

def construct(self):
    

    graph = Axes(
        x_length=6,
        y_length=3,
      )        
    

    matrix = [[2, -1],[-1, 3]]
    self.apply_matrix(matrix)

    self.wait(0)

    matrix2 = [[16/5, 2/5],[-3/5, 9/5]]
    self.apply_matrix(matrix2)
    self.wait()
```

Comment: maybe you should check [source code](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/scene/vector_space_scene.html#LinearTransformationScene). There is `self.foreground_plane_kwargs = {"x_range": np.array([-config["frame_width"], config["frame_width"], 1.0]),` - so it doesn't use `Axes` but settting from `config`